# How do I introduce a file into a remote repository whilst removing all prior history?

Tags: git

I have a script whose changes I have been regularly committing to my local repository (the requirement at the time was not for this script to be included as part of a shared repository - it was intended to exist solely on my local machine).

This script is now required to be included as part of a shared remote repository; however, whilst developing this script, I included some private customer data as part of testing.

As such, I now need to include this file as part of the shared remote and want to know what the best way to go about it is in order to remove all prior history/commits.

My initial thoughts are that I can make a copy of the file / relocate the file, then delete the repository from my local machine, pull the remote repository in and then introduce the new file into the freshly-pulled repository (in order to push back again).

I don't know if this is a good way to go about it or if there is some other, more efficient way to do this and am happy to hear of any solutions.

Comment: Does your local repository only contain commits for that file?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The method you outline is *very safe* and is therefore the way to go. Other methods might be more machine efficient. Machine efficiency is not a priority here.

Answer (score -1):

The method you suggested is a simple and good way to go, while also being very safe. I would do that, instead of risking exposing private customer data by accident.

Comment: What does this answer add when compared to torek's comment?

Comment: @Paolo probably nothing, except that it's an answer. It is often the case that people are providing answers in comments, but they really should be added as answers for people to vote on. Answers in comments are always subject to removal.